# spark straming. submit network_wordcount.py report error

Tags: python, pyspark

working env:

```
spark 2.2.0
python 2.7.9 
ipython 5.4.1
```

network_wordcount example.

run sacala script, success.

run python script, fail.

the error report:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:459092027
```

I search the spark bug page, the [problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7688) has been issued. But it not considered as as bug and closed. No any detail to show how to fix it.

Anyone knows? bow